# Getting the last modification time of a directory

Tags: php, linux, scripting, directory, timestamp

I understand this isn't the actual "modification" time of a directory, but I need the timestamp and I'm struggling to determine how to get it.  I'm actually going to use the output of this command in a PHP script, but I can't get the time.

```
stat -f "%y" zip
```

I keep getting the message `stat: cannot read file system information for '%y': No such file or directory`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%y` is used for defining the output format. You can only set the output format after the `-c` flag. What you want is:

```
stat -c %y zip
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use the SplFileInfo class to get the modification time of the directory

```
$test = new SplFileInfo(__DIR__); //use a path to your directory
echo  $test->getMTime();
echo date('Y-m-d',$test->getMTime());
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer find over stat. Find may have better formatting options and may be more consistent and available across platforms.

```
find zip -maxdepth 0 -printf "%TY/%Tm/%Td %TH:%TM:%.2TS\n"
2011/11/21 13:41:36
```

Be sure to include -maxdepth, otherwise find will dig out all the files under the directory.